# What kind of plant is this? Found a flower plant in my grocery parsley

Tags: identification, parsley

I recently bought parsley from my local market (didn't came in a plastic box, just grabbed it). When I opened it, I found this plant with a couple of purple flowers or leaves sticking out. I put it in water expecting it to die by the next day but, oh surprise... it grew roots. Lots! Two days later, I potted the plant with its roots in a terracotta pot outside but I didn't like it. I was kinda falling to the side and the windy day that we had did not help. So I took it out of the soil and put it back on water and it seemed to like it. However, I still do not know what kind of plant this is.. Is it normal that it came from the parsley? It seems to like the water so should I keep it there? Can I pot it? Can you help me identify it so I know what to do with it?

Btw it was Italian parsley.

Thanks!
[image: Plant in water][image: Plant potted before it almost died]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure  what it is - an open flower would help with ID. It looks vaguely like  *Catharansus*, but might not be.

If it's got a good root system, you can transfer it to a small pot with fresh potting soil, but don't put it outside, keep it inside for a few days,then harden it off over a week or so by leaving it outside in the middle  of the day, extending the hours its  outdoors till it is outside all night. Don't stand it in sunlight - choose a spot  outdoors that is shady or gets maybe a little sun early morning or late evening. If it turns out to be something you want to keep, as it starts to settle in, root properly into the soil and grow in the pot, gradual and increasing  sun exposure should be okay, depending on what plant it turns out to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is *Persicaria maculosa*, I am not sure what the common name in English is. Redshank? The vague black spots on the leaves remind of it. A mature flower would help to be sure. Where I live, in the Netherlands, it is considered a weed.